# Is it possible to know the form is shown with Show() or ShowModal()

Tags: delphi, c++builder

My Environment:
   C++ Builder XE4

Is it possible for FormB to know FormB is shown with Show() or ShowModal()?

At FormA:

```
void __fastcall TFormA::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    FormB->Show();
    // FormB->ShowModal();
}
```

At FormB:

```
void __fastcall TFormB::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
   // with some if sentence to know Show() or ShowModal()
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can test for `fsModal in FormState` at the onShowEvent of your form.

I've made you a small example:

Create a new project, and add an extra form to it. On the Main Form place two buttons, and let them display your second form:

```
uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.ShowModal;
end;
```

No magic here :D

Then add an `OnShowEvent` to your `Form2`:

```
    procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if fsModal in FormState then
        Caption := 'ShowModal'
      else
        Caption := 'Show';    
    end;
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: in C++ Builder, I could check with `if (FormState.Contains(fsModal)) {`